# android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception string resource id #0x0

Tags: android

I am getting this error when i m trying to get list of data from table by calling constructor from another class, 
my main file is

**Account.java**

```
            try{
                List<PersonalInformation> temp = helper.findAll();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(temp.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @Egor can u please tell me how to identify the error line as am facing the same error in my project

Comment: @AndroidOptimist, Check your logcat, find the exception stacktrace and find the line that's throwing the exception.